# Display:None on a pseudo elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have lots of vertical lines that are before `<a>` links, but I want to hide the third line.

Here is my CSS for my `<a>` before:

```
.header-social a:before {
//line style
}
```

I have tried using `nth-child()`, but i don't know how to use pseudo elements with `nth-child()`.

```
.header-social a:before:nth-child(4) {
  display:none;
}
```

Not sure how I could go into any more detail than I already have. Do I need JavaScript?

Comment: put your full code here.

Comment: can you show your html structure.  You will need the nth-child on either the a or the header social

Comment: Without your HTML we can only offer (educated) guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this:

```
.header-social a:nth-child(3)::before {
  color: red;
}
```

or  using `nth-of-type`

```
.header-social a:nth-of-type(3)::before {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: That worked, though i want the rest of social bar to align center as if that line isn't there at all. At the minute, it seems more like its hidden than actually gone. I'd know how to remove something in jquery, but this is a pseudo element so i cant use this:

$( ".header-social a:before" ).remove();